# cv::getPerspectiveTransform throws Error after cv::eigen2cv

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

**My Code**:

```
cv::Mat
    getPerspectiveTransform(Eigen::MatrixXd quadrangle, Eigen::MatrixXd warpedQuadrangle) {
        cv::Mat transMat;
        cv::Mat quad(4,2,CV_32FC1);
        cv::Mat warpedQuad(4,2,CV_32FC1);
        cv::eigen2cv(quadrangle,quad);
        cv::eigen2cv(warpedQuadrangle,warpedQuad);
        std::cout << "[        ] quadrangle in cv::Mat " << quad << std::endl;
        transMat = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(quad,warpedQuad);
        return transMat;
    }
```

**Error**:

```
C++ exception with description "OpenCV(4.6.0) /home/ci/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3392: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'getPerspectiveTransform'
```

**Suspected Issue**:
`eigen2cv` is converting my CV_32FC1 to CV_64F. `getPerspectiveTransform` is expecting CV32F as its input.

What should be the ideal solution to this?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/facing-errors-while-converting-eigen-matrixxd-to-cv-mat/9495

Answer (score 1):

`eigen2cv` changes the layout of output matrix according to type of the input matrix, as can be seen from its [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/139c44377032f58849bbab2ae454fcf14e89d762/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp#L100). So, e.g., if your Eigen matrices use 64-bit floats, output `Mat`'s will have `CV_64F` depth. In this case, the simplest solution is to convert output matrices to `CV_32F` using `Mat::convertTo` ([documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b)):

```
Mat quadF, warpedQuadF;
quad.convertTo(quadF, CV_32F);
warpedQuad.convertTo(warpedQuadF, CV_32F);
transMat = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(quadF, warpedQuadF);
```

Since matrices are pretty small, this conversion is unlikely to be a performance issue, but it's possible to avoid it by rewriting 2 overloads of `getPerspectiveTransform` function ([source1](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e16cb8b4a23fc1b6b7b99155a0d33f523262db76/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L3277) and [source2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e16cb8b4a23fc1b6b7b99155a0d33f523262db76/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L3389)) to work with 64-bit floats. Second overload just delegates to the first, and the first works with `double`'s internally anyway, so it's pretty trivial:

```
cv::Mat getPerspectiveTransform64(const Point2d src[], const Point2d dst[], int solveMethod)
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION();
    Mat M(3, 3, CV_64F), X(8, 1, CV_64F, M.ptr());
    double a[8][8], b[8];
    Mat A(8, 8, CV_64F, a), B(8, 1, CV_64F, b);
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        a[i][0] = a[i+4][3] = src[i].x;
        a[i][1] = a[i+4][4] = src[i].y;
        a[i][2] = a[i+4][5] = 1;
        a[i][3] = a[i][4] = a[i][5] = a[i+4][0] = a[i+4][1] = a[i+4][2] = 0;
        a[i][6] = -src[i].x*dst[i].x;
        a[i][7] = -src[i].y*dst[i].x;
        a[i+4][6] = -src[i].x*dst[i].y;
        a[i+4][7] = -src[i].y*dst[i].y;
        b[i] = dst[i].x;
        b[i+4] = dst[i].y;
    }
    solve(A, B, X, solveMethod);
    M.ptr<double>()[8] = 1.;
    return M;
}

cv::Mat getPerspectiveTransform64(InputArray _src, InputArray _dst, int solveMethod)
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat(), dst = _dst.getMat(); 
    CV_Assert(src.checkVector(2, CV_64F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_64F) == 4);
    return getPerspectiveTransform64((const Point2d*)src.data, (const Point2d*)dst.data, solveMethod);
}
```

This can now be used directly without additional conversion:

```
transMat = getPerspectiveTransform64(quad, warpedQuad);
```